# Summation of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^{2}kx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

It's easy to show that

$$\sin A-\sin B=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right),$$

$$\sin\left(2k+1\right)x-\sin\left(2k-1\right)x=2\cos2kx\cdot \sin x.$$

From this can we show

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^{2}kx=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)\cdot \cos\left(n+1\right)x}{2\sin x}$$

with the method of differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double angle formula gives $\sin^2(kx) = \frac{1 - \cos(2kx)}{2}$.

So we have

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n\sin^2(kx) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n\frac{1 - \cos(2kx)}{2} = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n\cos(2kx)$$

$$ = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4\sin x}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n2\cos(2kx)\sin x$$

$$ = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4\sin x}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n\left[\sin(2k+1)x-\sin(2k-1)x\right]$$

$$ = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4\sin x}\left[\sin(2n+1)x - \sin x\right]$$

$$ = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4\sin x}\left[2\cos(n+1)x\sin nx\right]$$

$$ = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{\cos(n+1)x\sin nx}{2\sin x}$$

Provided $\sin x \neq 0$, i.e. $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$. Though in these cases the equality is still true if taken as a limit.

---

You could also evaluate $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n\cos(2kx)$ using complex exponentials and geometric series, after taking real parts.

Comment: The double angle formula!!!